# How to Display a Different Image Each Day

Tags: jquery, image

I want to display a different image on my web page for each day of the week.. Can any one help me?

Comment: Define "each day". Server day? Client day? We live on Earth, which happens to be a globe. There is 24 hours between the first and the last timezone we have on this planet. It would be more sensible to do this server-side, unless the image displayed directly correlates with the day the user percieves it is (e.g. a giant flashing word "Wednesday", which should be displayed on what the user thinks is wednesday).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below code to solve your problem

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var imlocation = "images/";
 function ImageArray (n) {
   this.length = n;
   for (var i =1; i <= n; i++) {
     this[i] = ' '
   }
 }
image = new ImageArray(7);
image[0] = 'sunday.gif';
image[1] = 'monday.gif';
image[2] = 'tuesday.gif';
image[3] = 'wednesday.gif';
image[4] = 'thursday.gif';
image[5] = 'friday.gif';
image[6] = 'saturday.gif';
var currentdate = new Date();
var imagenumber = currentdate.getDay();
document.write('<img src="' + imlocation + image[imagenumber] + '">');
//--></script>
```